# Lucene keyword notification

Tags: lucene

What's the best way to get a notification (say an event) when a keyword is found in a document in Lucene?

The brute force way is to keep searching for the keyword in short intervals but that seems very inefficient as well as not as "real-time"

Comment: Unless I am missing something, how about looking through the tokens of the n+1th document when you are adding it? Why do you need to hit the entire index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at MemoryIndex:

http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_2_0/api/org/apache/lucene/index/memory/MemoryIndex.html

It's part of Lucene contrib, and it is designed for publish/subscribe systems that you're building.  However, it's been a while since I've looked at this, and I'm not sure if it's being actively maintained.

Comment: I think this is closest I can get to what I want. Although I'm not quite comfortable with the fact that it holds the index in memory. I'd rather have a scalable but slower solution.